# IIS Web App Deploy Task for Angular App : No package found with specified pattern

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

This problem has been reported multiple times but I can't found an answer to resolve it. I'm trying to deploy the result of the build of an angular app.

My IIS Web App Deploy Task fails with the following error:

```
2022-04-07T12:02:28.9289550Z ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern.
<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage 
and downloaded in the current job.
```

Which is weird because I chose the artifact folder with the assistant (The 3 dots button on the right) [...]:

[image]

which resulted with this folder in the configuration of the task:

[image]

What can be the source of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by recreating a release from the release pipeline.